# Handle TimeOut::Error with retry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout

I have an application running on Heroku that, on occasion, reports **Timeout::Error** and **(ActionView::Template::Error) "execution expired"**.

This happens all over the website (i.e. not in a specific controller) so I would like to create a function that will handle these two errors, first by retrying two times and the redirect the user to a page that will tell them that the server is busy.

My current plan is to use the following in ApplicationController:

```
  rescue_from Timeout::Error, :with => :rescue_from_timeout

  def rescue_from_timeout
    sleep 2
    retry 
  end
```

but this will just loop and loop. I want it to break after two attempts. How can I do that?

Also, How can I handle ActionView::Template::Error for "execution expired"? I don't want to rescue all ActionView::Template::Error with retries, only the ones that provoke the "execution expired".

This is what my exception says:

```
[Exception] home#index (ActionView::Template::Error) "execution expired"
```

or

```
[Exception] calculations#result (ActionView::Template::Error) "Timeout::Error: execution expired
```

My question, thus: How can I handle these two types of errors by first retry twice and then throw an exception / redirect to error page?

Comment: Why is this exception raised ? Did you implemented some sort of long-running tasks, does your app depend on an external web service ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Define this method:

```
def retryable(options = {})
  opts = { :tries => 1, :on => Exception }.merge(options)

  retry_exception, retries = opts[:on], opts[:tries]

  begin
    return yield
  rescue retry_exception
    if (retries -= 1) > 0
      sleep 2
      retry 
    else
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

And call with this:

```
retryable(:tries => 10, :on => Timeout::Error) do
  your_code_here
end
```

You could put this in an around_filter in the application controller, that is the base class for all controllers in a rails application:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  around_filter :retry_on_timeout

  def retry_on_timeout
    retryable(:tries =>  10, :on => Timeout::Error) do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Douglas. I am, however not sure where/how to use the calling code. If I want to use it so that it catches this error all over the website I would guess I would have something called in the app-controller as a before_filter or something. Do I need to wrap each controller etc with the retryable function? Could you please elaborate on how I can use this to catch the error all over the website (all controllers/views).

Comment: I edited the answer using an around filter in ApplicationController. Does this apply for you?

Comment: I cannot test it other than by keeping it online for a few days and see if it removes these error messages, but it seems to be working. Or, is there a way to provoke a TimeoutError so I can test it?

Comment: You could try to add this code: raise TimeoutError (please add the module before the constant Module::TimeoutError)

Comment: What is `sleep 2` for?

Comment: It is to wait 2 seconds before try again

Comment: :) I meant why wait? Why not try again right away? Is it somehow bad?

Comment: In my case it is advisable to wait a moment because it would probably fail again if retry immediately. It depends on your use case.